# Using second field for same column in entity for hashcode equals and entity management

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We are using spring data jpa with hibernate in our project.

Following is sample representation of entities.

```java
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long authorId;
 
    private String firstName;
 
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "author")
    private Book book;


 
    ...
}


@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Author author;

    ...
}
```

Please forgive any syntax issues.

We have only `OneToOne` association field for author in book entity.This has many drawbacks for our design.

1. Author is lazily fetched always.
2. We uniquely identify Book with Author id
3. We have `authorId` in book table as foreign key.
4. If you understand closely, we cannot use `authorId` to uniquely identify record, just because of hibernate lazy associations, in equals and hashcode contract even if we want to use it. If we use author association in equals and hashcode, it will eagerly call author entity for each book which we do not want.
5. Here, we previously had a roadblock, as `book.author.authorId` was being used in too many places and that requires additional join or to query author table just to get *only id*.

**To solve this we created another field authorId in Book entity.**

- With this field we can do like `book.authorId` in all queries without fetching author entity.
- This is way where we make `insertable` and `updateable` false as mentioned in many forums to have single column mapped to multiple fields.

```java
@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToOne
    private Author author;
    
    @Column(name = "authorId", insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private Long authorId

    ...
}
```

**I have tested following till now:**

1. Get with authorId works fine.
2. It works with hql jpql with basic tests
3. Not sure about limitations though.

**Questions are:**

1. What I understood is this field is readonly and set by hibernate for me, I should explicitly never update this field anywhere, is my understanding correct?
2. Can we safely use authorId presented as new field in hql/jpql and sql queries
3. Will this field be correctly managed by hibernate?
4. Do we need to set it explicitly? Eg: when I create Book, I can do like this

```java
Author author = repository.findById();
Book b = new Book();
b.setAuthor(author)
b.setAuthorId(author.getId)
```

also any other case where I explicitly need to set book.authorId ?
Will it be correctly managed then by hibernate?

Comment: Have you tried changing the field ```Book```in ```Author``` to ```List<Book>```. This way a one to many Mapping should work.

Comment: Agree with @fnymmm - why should an author be bound to exactly one book? Prefer using a one-to-many relation there.

Comment: first of all clarify your functional need, do you really want an author to have exactly 0 or 1 book? because that is what we see from your code provided

Comment: Will have exactly 1 book.
@fnymmm and Arno as I said in post, the entities are just imitation of real scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What I understood is this field is readonly and set by hibernate for me, I should explicitly never update this field anywhere, is my understanding correct?

Yes, as soon as the same field is used for association you cannot touch it. If you need to update value in the DB you must do it via updating `Book.author`. In your entity just create a private setter in your `Booke` entity to make sure the field won't be touched.

> 2. Can we safely use authorId presented as new field in hql/jpql and sql queries

You can, but you probably shouldn't. In your question above you wrote:

> Here, we previously had a roadblock, as book.author.authorId was being used in too many places and that requires additional join or to query author table just to get only id.

If you look into generated code you'll find out that there's no `join` clause generated as Hibernate is smart enough to take the value from `author_id` column of `Books` table. I. e. if you write JPQL-query like

```
select book from Book book where book.author.auhtorId = :authorId
```

the resulting query would be

```sql
select b.* from books b where b.author_id = ?`
```

> 3. Will this field be correctly managed by hibernate?

Yes, Hibernate relies mostly on reflection so even with private accessors the code is correct.

> 4. Do we need to set it explicitly?

No, you needn't do it. You need to care about `Book.author` because it's associated entity. As soon as `Book.authorId` is annotated with `@Column(name = "authorId", insertable = false,updatable = false)` Hibernate expects you won't update it, in terms of your code this is enough:

```java
Author author = repository.findById();
Book b = new Book();
b.setAuthor(author)
```

P.S. In the snippet above instead of `Author author = repository.findById();` you could use `Author author = repository.getById();` saving one DB call as `JpaRepository.getById()` returns a proxy with `id` instead of actually fetching data.